# Getting the error: ReadTimeout = 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' when using MemoryStream instance

Tags: c#, stream, naudio, memorystream

The specific message is "Timeouts are not supported on this stream'. I'm also getting a similar exception but for WriteTimeout.
This is my code. I am trying to write audio data to a MemoryStream instance (instead of writing to a file and using I/O operations). Ultimately I want to send this audio data in an POST request.

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Web;
using System.Media;

internal class Program
{
    static WaveInEvent? waveIn;
    private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        int deviceNo = GetDeviceNo();

        //starts recording
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start recording...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        waveIn = new WaveInEvent();
        waveIn.DeviceNumber = deviceNo;
        waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
        waveIn.DataAvailable += (sender, e) =>
        {
            stream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        };

        waveIn.StartRecording();
        Console.WriteLine("Recording...");

        Console.ReadKey();
        waveIn.StopRecording();

        Console.WriteLine("Recording stopped.");

        //Transcribing audio file to text using WhisperAI
        var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
        var modelContent = new StringContent("whisper-1");

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "key");

        var whisperCont = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        whisperCont.Add(fileContent, "file", "output.wav");
        whisperCont.Add(modelContent, "model");

        var whisperResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions", whisperCont);
        var whisperRespCont = await whisperResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var whisperRespObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WhisperData>(whisperRespCont);
        string ogText = whisperRespObj.text;
        Console.WriteLine(ogText);

        httpClient.Dispose();
        stream.Dispose();
    }

public class WhisperData
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

The exception is thrown anywhere after instantiation. I've searched for answers but they aren't relevant or don't work. I will edit the post accordingly if more code needs to be added for better context. I'm not experienced with this memory stuff. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you saw in the error stack trace exactly which line/instruction throws the exception, and make sure you're not ommiting crucial code or information, for example I don't know how to reproduce your error because I'm not sure which library you're using for your WaveInEvent and WaveFormat classes; there are multiple possible.

Comment: @ErroneousFatality I edited the post. I found out about the error while debugging line by line and saw the error messages while hovering over the MemoryStream instance. For context, this audio data is translated to another language and played back, but I couldn't play it using SoundPlayer from System.Media and i traced the error back to the MemoryStream instance.

Comment: This is not an exception that affects your program in any way.  A debugger's watch shows what it knows about an object, evaluating all fields and properties of a class.  Including the inherited members, like ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout.  But a MemoryStream does not have a meaningful implementation for them, memory access does not have a timeout.  Its CanTimeout property is *false*.  So that's what it you see.

Comment: Where are you filling the memory stream with audio.  Then after you fill you have to set position to zero before playing back.  Error indicates you never put audio into the stream.

Comment: @HansPassant So the error lies elsewhere? I am getting a "the wave header is corrupt" exception when the program tries to play the translated audio using the Play() method from SoundPlayer class.

Comment: The error lies elsewhere.  A .wav stream needs to be created with the RIFF format, but the posted code does nothing to create such a format.  https://www.markheath.net/post/how-to-use-wavefilewriter

Comment: @HansPassant The error was elsewhere indeed. The API I was using to translate the audio only accepts files. I assume raw data like that of a stream doesn't work with the API, and that's the only thing that needs to be changed so that my program works. Thanks